# Vuejs - how to get the path of a route by its name?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a vcard which links to a route. I've used the route name and passed params to it as shown below in the code and this works fine.

Problem is,  i need to use this same link somewhere else and pass it as a param as :link in share attribute.

ex: :link = the path of the route named "recipe_article"

Thanks in advance

```
<v-card 

    :to="{name:'recipe_article',params:{slug:this.featured[0].slug}}"                                                                       
>
    <v-list>                                                            
        <share 
            :link=recipe_article.$route.path 
            :ptitle=this.featured[0].title :pdesc=this.featured[0].body.substring(0,100) 
            :tags=this.featured[0].tags> 
        </share>
    </v-list>
</v-card>
```

Comment: Can you explain a but more, I am not clear on what you want to do?

Comment: Are you trying to get the href which corresponds with a given named route?

Comment: James Coyle : Yes, ex the route path is 'single/recipe/:slug'. i need to get that path

Comment: Does `this.$route.fullpath` help? you know the base of the route so just build a string with base+fullpath

Comment: Michael: It's not the current route, it's another route. i need to get the path of another route by it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [router.resolve](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-resolve) method to retrieve the href for a given route. I'm not sure how this handles the params.

```js
computed: {
    href() {
        return this.$router.resolve({
            name:'recipe_article',
            params: {
                slug: this.featured[0].slug
            }
        }).href
    }

}
```

Comment: i'll give it a try